# Insert a string in a string

Tags: c#

```
//Laver Array Liste
ArrayList Fields123 = new ArrayList();
Fields123.Add("12345");
Fields123.Add("67890");
Fields123.Add("09876");
Fields123.Add("54321");
Fields123.Add("12345");

//Som Variable
foreach (string tbOldField in Fields123)
{
    number = number + 1;

    string field + number = tbOldField;   
}
```

Dont know the syntax in C#. My problem is that I need the string field to be like:

```
String field1
String field2
String field3
String field4
String field5
```

but dont know how to get the "number" in so its is field(number).

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs the old days when C# doesn't have _Generics_. You can use `List<T>` instead. In your case, `Dictionary` could be better..

Comment: Not clear on what exactly you are asking. What output are you expecting? An array of key value pairs like `"field1": 12345` and `"field2": 67890`? Is the `field1` a variable name/key or is it simply a corresponding value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly do not use weakly typed `ArrayList` use type-safe generic collections such as `List<T>`.

Secondly, you can't construct a variable name by concatenating other variables like that.What you need is a `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
List<string> Fields123 = new List<string>();
Fields123.Add("12345");
Fields123.Add("67890");
Fields123.Add("09876");
Fields123.Add("54321");
Fields123.Add("12345");

Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
int number = 1;
foreach (string tbOldField in Fields123)
{
    values.Add("field" + number++, tbOldField);
}
```

Then you can get the values by using the corresponding key, for example: `values["field1"]`

Comment: Depending on what the values are being used for, it may be more appropriate to use Tuples rather than KVPs